# Nitrous-IO Console - How to enable the scroll bar up/downfor the console window?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nitrousio

I'm on Nitrous IO, and successfully working on for Ruby on rails application. But thing that is irritating me is the inability to scrollup or down on the console window.

Is there any I can enable that feature for the Heroku console window ? Please guide me.

Because of this issue, I'm unable to see the previous tracking on my command (CLI)/ console window. Please have a look at the image for what I'm looking out

[image]

Comment: What program is this? Is this ST?

Comment: I'm running on NitrousIO and it's RubyonRails application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CTRL + UP/DOWN 

Press CTRL + UP/Down key for navigation(scroll up and down).
```

Something off the topic:

```
use gem "quiet_assets" to suppress the assets logging in your terminal. 
You will be able to see just controller-> Model logs in your terminal. 
Hope you find this gem helpful.
```

Comment: Thanks...it helps...'gem "quiet_assets"' gives error stating "it's unknown command"

Comment: just write gem 'quiet_assets' in your Gemfile and do bundle install
then restart your server. you will see your assets related logs won't appear in your console. 
https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets#installation

Comment: You deserve it Ajay ! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Shift + PageUp/PageDown